# Only allowing 8 characters

Tags: c#, string, drag-and-drop

So I finally got my code working the way I want...but..

Upon drop, I want the title of the file dropped to show in a `MessageBox.Show`.

I have it working...but I only reads up to 8 characters. It will show the title perfectly of any title 8 characters or less.

Anything more than 8 characters shows as all caps and has a ~1 at the end.
Example: a file name Penguins.jpg will show "Penguins". A file name Penguinsarecool.jpg will show "PENGUI~1".

Here is a pic:

[image]

Please let me know if you need any other info.
I appreciate all your help!

Here is my code:

```
 public void B1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string B1fileName = ((string[])((DataObject)e.Data).GetData("FileName"))[0];
        string B1result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(B1fileName);
            MessageBox.Show(B1result);
    }
```

Comment: Curious if you did `new FileInfo(B1fileName).Name` what you'd get..

Comment: @crlic306, I'm looking at your other question asked at stackoverflow and you are using there the proper way of extracting filename, the same as I suggested below. So why did you change your code and asked for help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `DataFormats.FileDrop` instead of `"FileName"` as `GetData` argument. It specifies Windows file drop format. That should work:

```
public void B1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string B1fileName = ((string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop))[0];
    string B1result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(B1fileName);
    MessageBox.Show(B1result);
}
```

Comment: When I originally tried you suggestion, the "Path." kept erroring...so I kept trying different methods. Then I learned that you ***NEED*** "using System.IO" in order for Path. to work properly. Just tried your modification (again) and it worked perfectly! Thank you!